# Proving that Reverse[Reverse[x]]]=x

Tags: proof

It is clear that for any list $x$, `Reverse[Reverse[x]]=x`. I want to have Mathematica tell me that this is true. I have tried entering

```
Reverse[Reverse[x]] == x
```

Mathematica responds with "Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Reverse[x]." I suppose because Mathematica can only apply Reverse to lists.

How can I get Mathematica to tell me that

```
Reverse[Reverse[x]] == x
```

is true?

Comment: `Reverse` is an active function.  There is no built-in symbolic representation of `Reverse` upon which analysis can be carried out.  I have found that you can use *Mathematica*'s analysis capabilities on symbols which in the documentation are noted as being "suitable for symbolic manipulation."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that there is a fundamental misunderstanding here.

In Mathematica certain expressions are meant to represent mathematica statements.  `x > 1` is an example of this.  Other expressions are simply program code, which is *run* by the system, like in any other programming language.  An example is `Table[x, {x,10}]`.  Sometimes there is a level of overlap between these, e.g.  in `Abs[x] > 0`, `Abs[x]` *represents* the absolute value of some variable, but `Abs` is also a function that will be run and return the result of a computation, e.g. `Abs[{-1.2, -0.5, 0.6, 0.9}]`.

Now [`Reverse`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reverse.html) is purely a programming construct.  It is never used to represent any mathematical statement.  What you are asking is not within the builtin capabilities of Mathematica.  It is not able to take a general *program* and prove things about its behaviour.  It also does not have special features to work with *lists* as mathematical entities, similar to how it can work with complex numbers, Boolean values or variables representing them (and recently even with symbolic tensors).

So to sum up, it is not possible to get Mathematica to tell us that `Reverse[Reverse[x]] == x` in any reasonable manner.  `Reverse` is a programming construct which expects a certain kind of input which cannot be a symbol.

Comment: That's a quite interesting question due to the subtle matter you've explained. Notice that OP has never used mathematics reference. And it's ok to ask about `Equal`ity or being the `Same` within WolframLanguage/Mathematica world. And OP statement is not True in this world. It's up to OP to restrict assumptions better.

Comment: I think this is the reason the developers introduced `Inactive` in version 10:  so that symbols like `Reverse` can be deactivated for symbolic manipulation.  Do you agree with my comment to OP?

Comment: @QuantumDot Well, it can be inactivated, but Mathematica still doesn't have any functionality to prove things about *how code runs*, and I think `Reverse` is still meant to be a programming construct and not meant to represent maths ...

Answer (score 2):

Hypothesis: It is clear that for any **List** `x`, `Reverse[Reverse[x]]=x`

Disproof by Counterexample:

Let's `el1`:

(*This is an UpValue for `el1` so one can't argue we are messing with `List` itself. And there are no restrictions about lists contents.*)

```
List[el1, rest___] ^:= List[rest]
```

and

```
list = {1, 2, el1}
```

Then,

```
Reverse@Reverse@list === list
```

> False

So your statement is incorrect for `Lists` in general. You may want to restrict that to e.g finite sequences of integers and ask again :)

Comment: Yes, I was only thinking of finite sequences. Thanks for pointing out the unstated assumption.